# Update sort order of dropdown list in place

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list for a set of items. The items have several properties including "ModifiedDate", "CreatedDate", "Id" and "Name". The dropdown list is bound to Id and Name and is sorted by Name.

However, I would like to provide an option to the user to change the sort column to either of "ModifiedDate', "CreatedDate" or "Id". The user will also have an option to sort order "Ascending" or "Descending".

I can do so using ASP.NET MVC with Postback.

```
Class definitions

public class ItemList
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdDate")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastModifiedDate")]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

}


public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("List of Items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string SortBy { get; set; }

    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

C# code to render the view

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Json array

    string s = "[
        {\"id\": 1, name: \"A\", \"createdDate\": \"2019-01-16T14:07:11.01Z\", \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2019-01-31T22:45:33.33Z\"},
        {\"id\": 2, name: \"B\", \"createdDate\": \"2019-10-02T18:55:53.24Z\", \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2019-10-16T19:47:32.407Z\"},
        {\"id\": 3, name: \"C\", \"createdDate\": \"2015-12-31T16:15:46.94Z\", \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2018-08-08T14:03:02.773Z\"},
        {\"id\": 4, name: \"D\", \"createdDate\": \"2016-10-21T20:56:55.553Z\", \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2016-10-21T21:00:29.323Z\"},
        {\"id\": 5, name: \"E\", \"createdDate\": \"2018-08-10T18:51:30.907Z\", \"lastModifiedDate\": \"2018-08-10T18:51:30.907Z\"}
    ]";


    List<ItemList> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemList>(s);

    List<Item> items = list.OrderByDescending(k => k.LastModifiedDate).Select(k => new Item { Id = k.Id, Name = k.Name }).ToList();

    MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();

    model.Items = items;

    return View(model);

}
```

View Extract - Index.cshtml

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-6 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Items)</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, new SelectList(Model.Items , "Id", "Name"), "Select item", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Sort on:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownList("SortBy", new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem(){Text="Created Date", Value="CreatedDate"},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="Modified Date", Value="ModifiedDate"},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="Query Name", Value="QueryName"}
        }, "Value", "Text", "..Select.."))
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Sort Order:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownList("SortBy", new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem(){Text="Descending", Value="D"},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="Ascending", Value="A"}
        }, "Value", "Text", "..Select.."))
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Reload Item List" />
    </div>
    </div>
</div>        
</div>
```

Is it possible to update the dropdown list without having the refresh the page? Can I achieve this with a partial post back with jQuery?

Comment: Make an ajax call to fetch the correct data and change the dropdown with jquery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676811/refresh-rebind-one-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks, I think this will work!